# what do people use for presentation layer in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

One of the things that I don't like java is too many frameworks, and for everything you have to choose what to use...

I want to start a new web application, something like a small hostelworld.com I decided to use spring as DI and security framework. but still don't know which framework to use for the presentation layer. what framework do you usually use to create a **friendly UI** or what do you suggest me to use??

- plain html+ js framework (no java framework)
- richfaces
- Icefaces
- GWT
- ZK
- Vaadin
- wicket
- JSF 2.0
- name yours ??

I know it's a quite subjetive question and may not have a definite answer, but telling your experience with any of them will help everyone or people who are facing the same problem to decide what framework to use

Comment: This question is very subjective ... I use Wicket btw ;)

Comment: Great question, the problem is that very few people will have used enough of them in depth to give you an objective answer :-)

Comment: I know it's a quite subjetive question, but telling your experience with any of them will help everyone or people who are facing the same problem  to decide what framework to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Like mikera commented it is hard to say which one is better, if the answering person has used only a few of them, not all. If you have some time and good will and you really want to know which is the best, I could suggest the following:

- Check which technology has fanciest plugin to your favorite IDE. You'll see that already by searching little bit for tutorials for every one of them. I know that at least Vaadin has a GUI for Eclipse and I think many others also do have one.
- Why not consider a content management system? A good one is Liferay, for example. There you have tools for creating the content by ready tools and even the site can be managed by its own tools.

These are some general tips for the area, that may be usefull also for others :)

Answer (score 0):

I have started using [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) lately which is pretty decent and not as invasive as some other tools.

However, I have started looking into [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) which will let you create apps for apple, android, and Microsoft devices. This may not be what you are looking for, but with it you can create apps for these devices and share the back end code. It is really useful.

Asa a side note, Google's [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) is a really good DI toolkit. Here is a comparison of [Spring and Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/SpringComparison).

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used

- Apache Wicket
- Spring MVC + JSP
- JSF
- GWT

and for a webapplication which is not high frequently visited I recommend

- Apache Wicket

the most.

It has the clearest event based component and model approach and the lowest impact on the html templates I've seen till today.

Answer (score 0):

JSF 2(Mojarra) with Facelets as view technology. Primefaces for components is my latest favorite.